# Python code to check free space of a USB drive connected to the Linux machine

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

I want to know, is there any way to get free/available space of a usb drive when I connect it to a Linux machine. I extracted following code from internet. It is working for root drive. but I have no idea to set the path dynamically.

```
import os

disk = os.statvfs("/")

print""
print "~~~~~~~~~~calculation of disk usage:~~~~~~~~~~"
print""

totalBytes = float(disk.f_bsize*disk.f_blocks)
print "total space: %.2f GB" % (totalBytes/1024/1024/1024)

totalUsedSpace = float(disk.f_bsize*(disk.f_blocks-disk.f_bfree))
print "used space: %.2f GB" % (totalUsedSpace/1024/1024/1024)

totalAvailSpace = float(disk.f_bsize*disk.f_bfree)
print "available space: %.2f GB" % (totalAvailSpace/1024/1024/1024)
```

Help me to develop that code or any idea for another code to get details about free or available spaces of the usb drive I connected.

Comment: Just change the path in `statvfs` call. Depending on your distro the path will be something like `/media/<user>/<label>` (ubuntu) or `/mnt/<mount point>` (redhat).

Comment: Parse `/proc/mounts` or `/etc/mtab` (they may have escape sequences)?

Comment: @FreekWiekmeijer This works using the mount point. Is there any way to find the path dynamically?

Comment: You could do a `os.walk()` from `/media/` or `/mnt/`, respective the OS. Challenge is to define a proper exit condition for the iteration. Do you know the label of the USB drive? Or do you know a certain file or folder pattern that should be present? You can use that. Else, the output of `mount` would help as well.

Comment: @FreekWiekmeijer I want to do it without knowing about the usb driver name. Above code is best if I can get the path of the usb drive then it can be included into `ststvfs` I'l try `os.walk()` this looks helpful.

Comment: @FreekWiekmeijer I got the answer and answered below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at above answers, comments and looking some examples I did following code to find the answer to my problem. This worked well for me.

```
import os

def details(dev):

    fulldir = "/media/ravi/"+dev

    disk = os.statvfs(fulldir)

    print("")
    print"Driver name " + Name[x]
    print("")

    totalBytes = float(disk.f_bsize*disk.f_blocks)
    print "total space: %.2f GB" % (totalBytes/1024/1024/1024)

    totalUsedSpace = float(disk.f_bsize*(disk.f_blocks-disk.f_bfree))
    print "used space: %.2f GB" % (totalUsedSpace/1024/1024/1024)

    totalAvailSpace = float(disk.f_bsize*disk.f_bfree)
    print "available space: %.2f GB" % (totalAvailSpace/1024/1024/1024)

    print("------------------------------")

Name = os.listdir("/media/ravi/")
length = len(Name)
print(Name[-1])

for x in range(length):
    details(str(Name[x]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Refer http://walac.github.io/pyusb/ this link for usb programming in python

or

You can use subprocess module and run linux command :

First run  :  ls /media

to get the name of your usb device

df -h /media/DC4A-97B2/

Where DC4A-97B2 is the name of usb device

Comment: This works. But is there any dynamic way to get this path ?